# Nested loop not working as intended?

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to take one value from a cell and compare it to the rest to see if they are the same however my if statment is always true even though it shouldn't be? whats going on here?

```
    for(int i = 0; i < stuTable.getRowCount(); i++){
            Object seatNum = stuTable.getValueAt(i,0);
            int seatInt =  Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(seatNum));
            for(int j = 1; j < stuTable.getRowCount(); j++){
                Object seatNum2 = stuTable.getValueAt(j,0);
                int seatInt2 =  Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(seatNum2));
                if(seatInt == seatInt2){System.out.println(seatInt+":"+seatInt2);}
            }
    }
```

Comment: if I do that i get int cannot be dereferenced

Comment: @AntonH He's comparing primitive values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the inner loop where you are initializing `j` always with 1. It must be started one greater than current value of `i`.

It should be `j = i + 1` in inner loop.

Complete code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < stuTable.getRowCount(); i++){
        Object seatNum = stuTable.getValueAt(i,0);
        int seatInt =  Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(seatNum));
        for(int j = i + 1; j < stuTable.getRowCount(); j++){
            Object seatNum2 = stuTable.getValueAt(j,0);
            int seatInt2 =  Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(seatNum2));
            if(seatInt == seatInt2){System.out.println(seatInt+":"+seatInt2);}
        }
}
```

For detailed information read below comments.

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: That worked, Thank you. Could  you explain to me why method didn't work originally, didn't i set up j to always be 1 higher than i?

Comment: Why not. You are comparing the items next to `ith` position. If `i=1` then `j` will start from 2 and continue to 2,3,4...

Comment: If `j` is equal to `i` then both item are same.

Comment: @Wolf When `i = 0`, you started with `j = 1`.  But then the outer loop incremented `i` to 1, and your original code still started with `j = 1`.  So no, you didn't set up `j` to always be 1 higher than `i`.

Comment: @Braj You supplied 2 separate answers in one answer.  Please separate into two answers or edit your original answer

Comment: @demongolem Sorry I didn't get it. What you mean by two answers?

Comment: @Braj Well your answer is incorrect and could be downvoted. You did get the correct answer `j = i+1` in the comments though. I think you should highlight the fact that you did get the answer that the user was looking for.

Comment: OK I'll explain it more details in mu post itself.